# Script is not fetching data from php to ajax script after success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I don't really understand why this does not work - I have read a whole lot about this specific problem, but I must be missing something.

I want to alert the "echo" from the PHP - which it doesn't.

AJAX:

```
$("#SaveChangesEmail").click(function() {
    var newemail = $("#mynewemail").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkemail.php",
        data: {newemail:newemail},
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP (checkemail.php)

```
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        if($email == $row['myemail']){
            echo "This is your current email";
        }
        else if($email != $row['myemail']){
            $results = $con->query("
                UPDATE members SET 
                myemail='".$email."'
                WHERE m_id = '".$m_id."'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
            echo "Your email is changed";

        }
    } else {
        echo "Please provide a correct email";
    }
```

The database is updating, do the script itself runs perfectly, but after the "success" - it doesn't alert anything.

**UPDATE**

I have now tried this:

AJAX:

```
$("#SaveChangesEmail").click(function() {
    var newemail = $("#mynewemail").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkemail.php",
        data: {newemail:newemail},
        datatype: "text",
        success: function(data){
            if(data == 1) {
                alert("This is your current email");
            }
            else if(data == 2) {
                alert("Your email is changed");
            }
            else if(data == 3) {
                alert("Please provide a correct email");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

PHP (checkemail.php)

```
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        if($email == $row['myemail']){
            echo "1";
        }
        else if($email != $row['myemail']){
            $results = $con->query("
                UPDATE members SET 
                myemail='".$email."'
                WHERE m_id = '".$m_id."'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
            echo "2";

        }
    } else {
        echo "3";
    }
```

The console is returning the raw data (1,2,3) but the alert is still not showing!

Comment: just replace echo with `echo json_encode("Your email is changed");` as your expect output is json

Comment: Have you tired something else in alert (different from returned php data)  to ensure the success trigger is working?

Comment: Yes, I have tried using: `$("#UpdateResult").html(data);` and `$("#UpdateResult").show();` which works just fine. `echo json_encode("Your email is changed");` doens't work either.

Comment: Please see my update.